# I need to form a pixel matrix out of an image file

Tags: c++, image, pixel

I need some help doing the following in C++:
I have to read an image file (.bmp, .jpg, etc.) and as a result I have to form a pixel matrix in the form of an one-dimentional array. Is there a library I should use or any functions available for this purpose?

Thank you!

Comment: Answer for bmp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array

For jpeg try libjpeg

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/694080/10468 for JPEG and PNG.  For BMP and other formats, I know the question has been asked before and answers exist on S.O.

Comment: (and never mind the "on linux" part of that question - the libraries are multiplatform.)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries available for reading images in C.

Some pointers:

- http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html
- http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/